# VSCode shows wrong npm package info in package.json

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, package.json, npm-registry

When using the intellisense for `package.json` the information in there is old/incorrect. For example right now it says the latest version for `@angular/core` is `10.1.3` when in fact it should be `10.2.0`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/core

Is this a bug, or is there a setting somewhere to clear a cache or something to fix this?

[image: VSCode]